# RDMA: Can I safely remove spinlocks from mlx4_post_send() function for one sided RDMA operations?

Tags: multithreading, rdma

I am porting linux-rdma to a platform with minimal OS support, e.g., spinlocks are not supported. My application aims to have application-threads and a worker-thread.
The application-threads create and enqueue requests to a shared queue. The worker-thread continuously polls the queue and posts the requests.

Since I am accessing RDMA interface from a single-thread (the worker-thread), I am wondering if removing the spinlocks inside the mlx4_post_send(), mlx4_post_recv() and mlx4_poll_cq() is safe?

In case I would like to avoid the use of pthread_spinlocks_t while having many connections (ideally one QP per thread), what would be the best workaround? My application does not involve data races -- namely, each thread will only invoke send()/post() for its own QP.

Thanks,
-dimitra

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is safe.  If you check the code for the mlx5 provider you can see that single-threaded mode was added (`MLX5_SINGLE_THREADED=1`).  I guess nobody went back and added it to the older mlx4 provider.

The official way to handle this would be to use `ibv_alloc_td` and then allocate the QPs in that thread domain, but that doesn't really help in your case.